# How to make Oracle SQL Output anonymous?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem concerning an output, which is created by Oracle SQL. Here is an example:

```
SELECT e.firstname, e.lastname 
FROM employee e
```

This SQL Statement created the following output:

```
Max, Mayer
Lisa, Trump
Marc, Zupper
```

Now I need a solution like this:

```
MXX, MXXXX
LXXX, TXXXX
MXXX, ZXXXX
```

It is important, that all existing characters will be make anonymous by using the character 'X', but not the first letter. In which way I can created an output like this? How can I solve this Problem?

Many thanks !

Comment: using concat and regex_replace, this should be simple

Comment: I don´t think, that is easy. Please show me a way of solution

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of `substr()` and `rpad()` for this:

```
SELECT substr(e.firstname,1,1)||rpad('X', length(e.firstname) - 1, 'X'), 
       substr(e.lastname,1,1)||rpad('X', length(e.lastname) - 1, 'X'), 
FROM employee e
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, here is a way with regex

```
SELECT regexp_replace(e.firstname, '.', 'X',2), 
       regexp_replace(e.lastname, '.', 'X',2) 
FROM employee e
```

Answer (score 0):

Below query will display as you expected

```
select rpad(substr(e.firstname,1,1),length(e.firstname),'X') as firstname,
    rpad(substr(e.lastname,1,1),length(e.lastname),'X') as lastname
     from employee e
```